# WPF Window style not working when used as activex object

Tags: wpf, vb.net, com, activex

I am creating a WPF Window (VB.NET) with a button:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource RoundButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="9.4,227.4,10.6,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168.4" >

            <Grid Width="148.333" Height="31.667" Margin="0,0,20,0">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="test" Margin="72,0,0,0" Width="73.479"/>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
```

When i start that exe i getting following Window:

[Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSPbY.png)

OK nice, but when i start the Window within a ComClass and STAThread (and registering with Regasm.exe) the style of the Button is gone:

[Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJvIT.png)

What can i do?

The style in Application.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="RoundButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF081863"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border x:Name="border"  CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="1">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FF003B63"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </Style>
```

Comment: Maybe the issue is that the style isn't accessible when the window is within a ComClass?  I suspect that Application.xaml isn't a good choice for where to keep this style (and I doubt you need it within that file).

Comment: @Craig Thanks, that was in fact the problem. I made the style directly into the xaml and now it works.